# changing the logistic regression threshold in SAS

Tags: sas, logistic-regression

How do I change the threshold value of predicted probability in a logistic regression model where the dependent variable is binary? This value is set at 0.5 by default by the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

> PPROB=value
>   PPROB=(list)
>   specifies one critical probability value (or cutpoint) or a list of critical probability values for classifying observations with the CTABLE option. Each value must be between 0 and 1. A response that has a cross validated predicted probability greater than or equal to the current PPROB= value is classified as an event response. **The PPROB= option is ignored if the CTABLE option is not specified.**

Depending on what you're looking for there may be other ways. I'd also check to make sure it was applied in place where I was expecting it to be, i.e. output tables as well was CTABLE.

```
proc logistic data=sashelp.heart  ;
class sex smoking_status;
model status = sex smoking_status weight/ctable pprob=0.7;
output out=want;
run;quit;
```